# ASP.NET Core REST API, CQRS, sorting and filtering

Tags: architecture, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm developing REST API using ASP.NET Core.

Schematic structure of app is as follows:

[image]

The algorithm works as follows:

1. A user sends a request
2. The request is processed by middlewares
3. The request comes into the controller
4. The controller processes the request, creates a Query, and Query Handler performs QueryHandler.Execute (Query)
5. QueryHandler receives data from the database and returns DTO
6. The controller creates an instance of the resource and returns it
7. The resource is processed by the middleware (e.g. cut off fields that are not parameter? fields).
8. The user receives JSON.

In my app I want to have ability to sort data (e.g.?Sort=title, -rating) and filter data (e.g.?Fields=id, title, genres (name). But I don't know how to create such abilities.

Question: how should I send information about sorting and filtering from API layer to DAL?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it would just be a List options added to your MovieRequest object.  FieldSort would have a field name and a directional value.

You would also have a List objects added to the MovieRequest, FieldFilters would have fieldName and value options... alternatively you could do a QBE pattern and pass in a stubbed out MovieResource as the filter.  I personally prefer being explicit about the filter objects, but YMMV.